# Is there a community for such a question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

The question would be about whether XYZ is a good way to have someone understand that their behavior ABC is wrong (from the social perspective).

To me this topic seems pretty close to pedagogy/education, but I don't find any site for this. There exist one where such a question would fit at least a bit?

Probably I should have written my true question since the beginning. However, here it is:

> This is the setting:
>
> - I'm with my son in a dinosaur park in a day not busy at all
> - my son starts kicking a dinosaur sculputure
> - I tell my son he should not do that
> - he asks why
>
> What are the pros and cons of the following answers?
>
> - "The watchmen will reprimand you if he sees you"
> - "Because I say so"
> - "Because other kids like you have right to ... and you should respect ..."
> - "Because I will beat you"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your question relates to being a parent, which this seems to, then [Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/) would seem like the best fit.

Look at [what's on-topic](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and what's off-topic.

Your question would seem to fit under the title of *"behavior and social skills"*, but I'm not a Parenting user and so it's worth looking at similar questions to see if yours might need more detail or some changes to make it more likely to succeed.

Answer (score 3):

The first one to come to mind is [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which is about exactly what its name suggests.

Depending on the scenario, other sites may fit as well:

- For academic relationship (e.g. a student and their advisor), [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) accepts such questions
- For work-related problems (e.g. your colleague), [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is open

Regardless of which site you choose to post your question, I'd suggest you reword your question into

> How to inform someone that their behavior ABC is wrong?

This is for two reasons:

- "whether XYZ is a good way" may be too subjective for SE
- you're probably making an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) where your actual goal is to let someone know they’re wrong, *not* whether the method is a good one